# HTML Div Float Will not center

Tags: css, html, styles

I am trying to make it so two uneven columns are close together, but I'm not sure where I went wrong while I was writing the code.
When these are entered, the columns span the width of the page, where I would like this to be about 720px total, with the main column being 520px and the secondary column being 200px.

I've tried about 30 different things, changing nearly all the variables, and adding random "align=/:center"'s around all the divs.

I'm not quite sure, and I could really use some help.
I've been working on this the last 5 hours of work, and this needs to be done, I cant quite get it :(
Thank you so much!

```
    <style>



.table { border:0px solid black; padding:10px; max-width:723px; overflow:hidden; }
.left {  float:left; width:75%; }
.right {  float:right; width:25%;  }


</style>




</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<center>

  <table style="display: inline-table;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="723">

    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><img name="gala_r1_c1" src="/images/gala_r1_c1.jpg" width="720" height="42" border="0" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><img name="gala_r2_c1" src="/images/gala_r2_c1.jpg" width="720" height="283" border="0" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>

      </center>




<div class="table">

    <div class="left">
            <h1>From the President</h1>
        <p></p>
        <p>Dear Friends,</p>
        blah
    </div>

    <div class="right">  

    <h1>From Students</h1> 
       -&quot;<b>derp&quot;<br>
          </b>
    </div>        
</div>



</center>


{embed="embeds/global_footer"}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didnt define the class names for your HTML elements

Comment: How would I define these class names? -OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

left    .table { border:0px solid black;
             padding:10px; 
             max-width:723px; 
             overflow:hidden;
             margin:0 auto; }

So, add `margin:0 auto;` to the `table` class.

Update:

```
<style type="text/css">

<style>
```

Remove one of them... :)

Instead this:

```
<div class="right"> <div class="right" padding-right="100px"> <h1>From Students</h1> -&quot;<b>derp</b> </div> </div>
```

try with this:

```
<div class="right"> <div style='padding-left:15px'> <h1>From Students</h1> -&quot;<b>derp</b> ....</div> </div>
```

Comment: This didn't work, is there something else that needs doing?

- OP

Comment: Wonderful!  I feel stupid, but thanks for the answer!  It's updated now, any chance you would know how to add a bit of a margin around the div?   So the two sections dont run into each other?  :)

Comment: Np, wrap content of right column in one div, and set some padding, 15px left will do the job...

Comment: I added padding-right:15px; to the div.  This is what I have so far:
 <div class="right" padding-right="15px">  
 
 <h1>From Students</h1> 
       -&quot;<b>derp</b>
    </div>

I fixed it by changing the width %age by 5%.  this seemed to work.  Now to get a background image :)
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: No, MAKE new div INSIDE div with class right, and add padding to that div (otherwise, right column div width will be bigger than 25%).

Comment: Well, see what happens now.  http://newhope.edu/index.php/static/Gala   
And here's the code I wrote.  

    <div class="right">
 <div class="right" padding-right="100px">  
 
 <h1>From Students</h1> 
       -&quot;<b>derp</b>
 </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 changes you will need to make:

1) MOST IMPORTANT - you need a doctype! Otherwise this pushes the browser into quirks mode and into otherwise no man's land. Always include this: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">`

2) Remove the dangling `</center>` tag at the bottom.

3) Add `margin: 0 auto;` as the gentleman before me posted. This the css equivalent to the html `<center>` tag.

Final results:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Float center</title>

   <style>



.table { border:0px solid black; padding:10px; max-width:723px; overflow:hidden;  margin: 0 auto;}
.left {  float:left; width:75%; }
.right {  float:right; width:25%;  }


</style>




</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<center>

  <table style="display: inline-table;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="723">

    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><img name="gala_r1_c1" src="/images/gala_r1_c1.jpg" width="720" height="42" border="0" 

alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><img name="gala_r2_c1" src="/images/gala_r2_c1.jpg" width="720" height="283" border="0" 

alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>

      </center>




<div class="table">

    <div class="left">
            <h1>From the President</h1>
        <p></p>
        <p>Dear Friends,</p>
        blah
    </div>

    <div class="right">  

    <h1>From Students</h1> 
       -&quot;<b>derp&quot;<br>
          </b>
    </div>        
</div>


{embed="embeds/global_footer"}
</body>
</html>
```

Snapshot:

[image: final result]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helped a lot more that you'd know!